# MVC 3 razor TextBoxFor with ViewBag item throws an error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor, viewbag

Trying to print out several different forms on the webpage with the data that i have received from the ViewBag.

The first statement works but no the second:

```
@Html.EditorForModel(ViewBag.PI as PItem)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => (ViewBag.PI as PItem).Text)
```

I also tried the following (same error message):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => ViewBag.PI.Text)
```

The first one creates a model for the PItem and the second throws an error when i try to create a textbox for the Text item inside PItem. Is it possible to use the textboxfor helper to print out data from the ViewBag and not from the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TextBoxFor` is intended to be used with strongly typed views and view models. So cut the `ViewData/ViewBag` c..p and use those helpers correctly:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Text)
```

If you need to loop, use EditorTemplates:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and inside the corresponding editor template:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Text)</div>
```

Not only that now we have IntelliSense and strong typing but in addition to this the code works.

Conclusion and my 2¢: don't use ViewBag/ViewData in ASP.NET MVC and be happy.

Comment: Ok, so instead of using ViewBag i should send the data in the Model. But how do i pass the model data to the layout page? Since i want to render one of the forms inside the layout page.

Comment: @Patrick, you could use child actions and the [Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helper.

Comment: Is there an example anywhere? My problem is that i can access the ViewBag from the layout but not the model. If i then add the information about our search to the model, then i can't render it in the layout.